# Wpf TextBox databinding update

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a TextBox and it is binded to a string property:

TextBox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="SearchBox"
     Text="{Binding SearchText, Source={StaticResource SearchEngine}, Mode=TwoWay}"
</TextBox>
```

and the class which is binded to:

```
public class SearchEngine : ViewModelBase 
{
    private string _searchText = string.Empty;

    public SearchEngine() {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("this = {0}", this);
        SearchText = "Search";
    }

    public string SearchText 
    {
        get { return _searchText; }
        set 
        {
            if (_searchText != value) 
            {
                _searchText = value;
                Console.Out.WriteLine("AAAAAAAAAAAA: " + value);
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I type in the TextBox, the `SearchText` doesn't get updated.

Comment: `NotifyPropertyChanged();` why this call without property name? Also, check your `UpdateSourceTrigger` property. If you want to update property when you typing, use `PropertyChanged` value

Comment: I don't think you can use `SearchEngine` as a static resource. Have you implemented NotifyPropertyChanged() properly?

Comment: Im sure tat the `NotifyPropertyChanged()` is implemented correctly. can you explain little more about `UpdateSourceTrigger`

Comment: ` UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` see : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the updatesourcetrigger in your xaml like:

```
<TextBox x:Name="SearchBox" Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
<TextBox x:Name="SearchBox" Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

and in your code-behind assign the DataContext property to your instance, i.e.

```
SearchEngine searchEngine = new SearchEngine();
SearchBox.DataContext = searchEngine;
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx).